# Whats the quickest way to accomplish this in Css with cross browser compatibility?

Tags: html, css

how do you get css to display angled texts?

[image]

i have

```
<span class="wrapper">
<span class="alpha">Alpha</span>
<span class="seperator"></span>
<span class="number">1 Number</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Are you asking about rotated text or subindex and superindex?

Comment: just the separator span it has a border and height is set to 1px position is absolute.

Comment: You mean [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/gKyVA/1)? This will work in IE9+

Comment: Thank you @Vucko yes i got it done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need only the separator rotated, here's an example: http://jsbin.com/yupozo/1/edit
it basically draws the separator as a regular line, then rotates it with `transform:         rotate(-45deg);`.

Do take care of non-supporting browsers with Modernizr and probably a `/` character or image. Dynamic rotating text is harder, but make sure if you need to support IE8 or below (See [Can I Use CSS Transforms?](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform)).

Comment: Thank you @Ronny that's what i wanted, but you gave me an idea that made me crack my head upto the wall a few times i can simply use an image in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="alpha">Alpha</div>
<div class="seperator"></div>
<div class="number">1 Number</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{display:block; width:200px; height:200px; border:1px solid #000; position:relative;}
.wrapper .alpha{position:absolute; top:10%; left:10%; float:left;}
.wrapper .seperator{float:left; position:absolute; top:50%; width:100%;
height:auto; border: 1px solid #000; transform: rotate(135deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(135deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);}
.wrapper .number{position:absolute; bottom:10%; right:10%; float:right;}
```